# Exacerbation for Contract issue exposed by Berlin Fork

Tags: solidity

Is there a way to "get round" an issue that had apparently always been present in a contract method but didn't used to fail prior to the Berlin fork? Specifically this:

`_breedWith(uint32(_matronId), uint32(_sireId));`

The issue (I think) is that the _breedWith method is as follows:

`function _breedWith(uint256 _matronId, uint256 _sireId) internal {`

Essentially my premise is the erroneous conversion to uint32 before calling the method is calling the _breedWith function to fail.

My question is 2 fold:

- does this seem like an explanation as to what is going on here? (The last successful call on this method was 14th April 2021 which was the day of the Berlin fork)
- with the assumption that it is unrealistic to be redeploy the contract is there anyway resolve this issue?

Comment: if there was no changes to the EVM during Berlin fork, then your issue has nothing to do with Berlin fork. We gave to check what changes were made and find out

Comment: I agree with Nulik. Depending on the types involved but a cast should be only bit shifts and masking. It is unlikely to be the cause of a bug in the Berlin fork https://blog.ethereum.org/2021/03/08/ethereum-berlin-upgrade-announcement/. If I have to point to possible problems I'd start with the opcode gas cost changes.